# Is it possible to set the position and size of audio controls?

Tags: css, html, html5-audio

I have an audio tag where the controls are not initially shown, and display them if the user clicks on a link like this:

```
var audio = document.getElementById(audioId);
if (audio.paused) {
    audio.src = clip;
    audio.play();
    audio.setAttribute("controls", "controls");
}
else {
    audio.removeAttribute("controls");
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
}
```

clip is the url of the audio file to play.

The audio is like this:

```
<audio id="audio1"></audio>
```

How can I set the position of the controls and is it also possible set their size?

The audio tag is a child of a list element, for all the other list elements I position them such as

```css
#track_title {
    position:absolute;
    top: 2px;   
    left: 80px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to control the html5 audio player controls via CSS for html5 audio tag. Though you may want to leave the default controls and implement your own controls via javascript.

However there is a nice existing html5 themable player called [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/)   which proves to be very useful.

Comment: Thanks, is it not even possible to position the location of the default controls with css?

Comment: I doubt that too. But I would highly advise you creating your own controls via javascript. this will also take care of progressive enhancements. Say if tomorrow an update is released to player and them maybe your controls may break if you try to  style them using css to meet your current needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Media API to build your own set of controls, allowing you to style them as you wish via CSS just like any other HTML elements. I wrote about how to do this over on the Adobe Developer Connection: [Working with HTML5 multimedia components – Part 3: Custom controls](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/html5-multimedia-pt3.html) .